# Text changed event not getting in Listener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a Listener to be called when text gets changed. However to avoid stack overflow, I am removing and re-adding the text changed event. Unfortunately the function never gets called and the text never changes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public TMP_InputField customTextField;

public void Start () {
        customTextField.onValueChanged.AddListener (TextChangedEvent);
    }

    public void TextChangedEvent (string newText) {
        customTextField.onValueChanged.RemoveListener (TextChangedEvent); //Remove Listener

        customTextField.text = newText.Replace ("0", "₀");
        customTextField.text = newText.Replace ("1", "₁");
        customTextField.text = newText.Replace ("2", "₂");

        customTextField.onValueChanged.AddListener (TextChangedEvent); //Add Listener back
    }
```

Comment: Your set of replacements there are probably fairly pointless; only the last one really takes effect. Consider `customTextField.text = newText.Replace ("0", "₀").Replace ("1", "₁").Replace ("2", "₂");` one liner instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why assignt he text multiple times then everytime only replace again from the original text?

Currently either way you will only end up with

```
customTextField.text = newText.Replace ("2", "₂");
```

and throw away the results of your previous `Replace` operations.

You rather want to apply the `Replace` sequencially e.g. on the `newText` itself so you use the result of the first `Replace` call as input to the next one!

```
newText = newText.Replace ("0", "₀");
newText = newText.Replace ("1", "₁");
newText = newText.Replace ("2", "₂");
```

which of course you can also simply do in a single line

```
var replacedText = newText.Replace ("0", "₀").Replace ("1", "₁").Replace ("2", "₂");
```

---

And then note that there is `TMP_InputField.SetTextWithoutNotify` which does exactly what you want:

> Set Input field's current text value without invoke `onValueChanged`

```
public void TextChangedEvent (string newText) 
{
    customTextField.SetTextWithoutNotify(newText.Replace ("0", "₀").Replace ("1", "₁").Replace ("2", "₂"));
}
```

---

Alternatively you could also already replace these symbols while the user is typing it using [`TMP_InputField.onValidateInput`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_onValidateInput) like e.g.

```
public TMP_InputField customTextField;

private void Start()
{
    customTextField.onValidateInput -= OnValidateInput;
    customTextField.onValidateInput += OnValidateInput;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    customTextField.onValidateInput -= OnValidateInput;
}

private char OnValidateInput(string text, int charindex, char addedchar)
{
    switch (addedchar)
    {
        case '0':
            return '₀';

        case '1':
            return '₁';

        case '2':
            return '₂';

        default:
            return addedchar;
    }
}
```